# React Native upload file using fetch, server $_FILES return object, how to access tmp_name

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

i have some problem with upload image from react-native to server directory. i tried many times, hours to solve this but got nothing. i also googled this but icant find the solution, i hope in this community someone can help me. so, below is my configuration:

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-image-picker": "^3.1.4",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
```

upload_image.php on server

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

this is how i upload file

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
      'POST',
      'http://[REDACTED]/api_sertifikat/upload_image.php',
      {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      [
        // element with property `filename` will be transformed into `file` in form data
        {name: 'image', filename: 'avatar.png', data: this.state.pic},
      ],
    ).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      alert('your image uploaded successfully');
      this.setState({avatarSource: null});
    });
  };
```

Response from server

```
[Sun Jan 31 2021 16:41:33.974]  LOG      {"array": [Function anonymous], "base64": [Function anonymous], "blob": [Function anonymous], "data": "array(1) {
  [\"image\"]=>
  array(5) {
    [\"name\"]=>
    string(10) \"avatar.png\"
    [\"type\"]=>
    string(24) \"application/octet-stream\"
    [\"tmp_name\"]=>
    string(14) \"/tmp/phpHeBX4W\"
    [\"error\"]=>
    int(0)
    [\"size\"]=>
    int(94)
  }
}
", "flush": [Function anonymous], "info": [Function anonymous], "json": [Function anonymous], "path": [Function anonymous], "readFile": [Function anonymous], "readStream": [Function anonymous], "respInfo": {"headers": {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Connection": "Keep-Alive", "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "Date": "Sun, 31 Jan 2021 09:41:33 GMT", "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "Server": "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)", "Vary": "Accept-Encoding"}, "redirects": ["http://[REDACTED]/api_sertifikat/upload_image.php"], "respType": "", "rnfbEncode": "utf8", "state": "2", "status": 200, "taskId": "5bt3eellca6y8xel6lu8w", "timeout": false}, "session": [Function anonymous], "taskId": "5bt3eellca6y8xel6lu8w", "text": [Function anonymous], "type": "utf8"}
```

Expected response, similar like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["something_name"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(44) "WhatsApp Image 2021-01-26 at 7.40.39 PM.jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE87D.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(114133)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## use `json_encode` instead of `var_dump`

The problem you're facing is that the server is not responding with data that your react-native application can use.

PHP's `var_dump` is not intended to produce a data encoding that's suitable for consumption by other computers. What it does produce is text that helps a *human developer* understand the type and value of a variable.

Now, it's true that you might be able to write some javascript that could parse the output of `var_dump`, but that could be surprisingly difficult, and it's just not worth it. It is *far better* to modify your PHP to return exactly the data needed by your mobile app, in a format your mobile app can consume easily.

My PHP skills are really rusty, this question was asked 6 months ago with no activity since then, so I suspect OP has moved on and there's no real value in my going to the effort of putting together a working code sample. (I did a little bit of research just now, and was horrified to see how clumsy PHP is. It's hard for me to believe I worked in PHP for six years.)

Perhaps another SO user will put that answer together to earn sweet internet points.

Comment: yeaa i got it man. some time ago i using var_dump is just to see what is inside $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is just access as usual `$_FILES['tmp_name']`, and work fine.